# num of vowels in ruby

Tags: ruby, count

I am fiddling around with some practice problems for ruby off the APP academy admissions. One particular problem that I am having trouble understanding why my solution is not working.

The problem

```
# Write a method that takes a string and returns the number of vowels
# in the string. You may assume that all the letters are lower cased.
# You can treat "y" as a consonant.
```

Here is my code for the solution which fails the tests.

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowels = 0
  word = string.split()
  idx = 0
  while idx <= word.length
    current_char = word[idx]
    if (current_char == "a"||current_char =="e"||current_char=="i"||current_char=="o"||current_char=="u")
      vowels += 1
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  return vowels 
end
```

this is the solution provided that works.

```
def count_vowels(string)
  num_vowels = 0
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if (string[i] == "a" || string[i] == "e" || string[i] == "i" || string[i] == "o" || string[i] == "u")
      num_vowels += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return num_vowels
end
```

Comment: Before posting on forum follow the rules to post.

Comment: Hint: [`String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count) Also I am not sure what site is recommending that you use a `while` loop in ruby but that is not the site I would want to learn ruby from

Comment: The irony that the "example solution" is about the least effective and most inefficient way of the many different ways this could be accomplished.... The real challenge would be to "Find a way to do this a more inefficient way than this"

Comment: I can see there're several solutions below. Now you might care about the complexity of these ones by implement them any measure the complexity to find the good one.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) by default splits a string into words, on whitespace:

```
"test string split".split() # => ["test", "string", "split"]
```

So, your solution is counting the number of full words that are equal to a vowel (words such as "a" and "I" by themselves). Yours would work if you split instead into characters by passing `''` as a parameter to `split`:

```
"test string split".split('') # => ["t", "e", "s", "t", " ",
  "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", " ", "s", "p", "l", "i", "t"]
```

However, there are better ways to get each character in the string, such as [`String#each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
"test string split".each_char { |char| # increment counter if char is a vowel }
```

and going further, you can simply use [`String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-count) to count the number of vowels:

```
"test string split".count('aeiou') # => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment above you could make your implementation simpler by using String's `count` method:

```
 def count_vowels(string)
   string.count('aeiou')
 end
```

Comment: Although your example is more robust and flexible, in OP's exact example, the `downcase` would not even be necessary, as it states you can assume all the vowels are lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it should be `word = string.split("")`

Above snippet splits string into an array.